# Building SQL Join for complement of data. T-SQL help needed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Assume I have data as,

```
declare @TableA table
(
  TableAID int,
  TableAName varchar(10)
)

declare @TableB table
(
  TableBID int,
  TableBName varchar(10),
  TableAID int
)

insert into @TableA values
(1, 'A 1'),
(2, 'A 2'),
(3, 'A 3')

insert into @TableB values
(1, 'B 1', 1),
(2, 'B 2', 2)
```

I want to write a join and NOT SQL query which returns me data just as shown below,

```
TableAName TableBName
---------- ----------
A 3        N/A
```

In short get a complement of the view with Inner Joins!

Comment: what is a `join and NOT SQL query` ? Did you try something ?

Comment: Are you actually using both MySQL and SQL-Server at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use for an `OUTER JOIN` and most commonly this is done using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (commonly abbreviated to just `LEFT JOIN`)

```
SELECT A.TableAName, B.TableBName
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B on A.TableAID = B.TableAID
WHERE B.TableAID IS NULL
```

An outer join allows unequal record numbers, here TableA has 3 but TableB has 2. When there is no matching data in TableB NULLs will exist, and hence you can filter for NULL as shown above.

Please do yourself a favour, go [here for a visual representation of joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)
& look for **Left Excluding JOIN**

Comment: I'll leave the educating to you :-)