# SQL Update From Table Prevent Duplicates Performance

Tags: sql, sqlperformance

I am trying to update a join table with keys from two other tables.  The join table (TableC) is already populated with several million keys from TableA.  The query as follows updates all rows in less than two minutes (very acceptable); however, where similar rows exist, each row should be matched uniquely.  (Keys from TableB should not be duplicated in TableC -- each record in TableA should be matched to a unique record in TableB.)

```
UPDATE TableC
SET TableC.TableBkey = b.TableBkey
FROM TableC AS c
INNER JOIN TableA AS a ON a.TableAkey = c.TableAkey
INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON b.col1 = a.col1 AND b.col2 = a.col2 AND b.col3 = a.col3
WHERE c.TableBkey IS NULL
```

This makes the query run indefinitely without updating any records; possibly the join fails to complete.

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 TableBkey FROM TableC AS x WHERE x.TableBkey = b.TableBkey)
```

Are there any other methods that would restrict duplicate keys from TableB without killing performance?  I would prefer not to use triggers.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan for the query?  Where's it being blocked?  What is the state of indexes?

Comment: Do you mean the b.TableBkey should not be updated into TableC.TableBkey if it already exists in TableC column TableBkey?

Comment: How about replace tableB with a subquery that look for records in tableB with tableBkey not in tableC.tableBkey?  Use Left outer join to get the complement of the join.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849807/building-sql-join-for-complement-of-data-t-sql-help-needed

Comment: If there are duplicate match keys in the target, then if you ran this update query twice, it will update arbitrary records in each case. If you are trying to update only one of many possible matches each time, yes that will happen, but every time you run the update it will pick an arbitrary match.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid.  There are no duplicate keys, only similar records.  Provided the three columns match, it is not critical which keys are matched as long as they are matched one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TableC
SET TableC.TableBkey = b.TableBkey
FROM TableC AS c
INNER JOIN TableA AS a ON a.TableAkey = c.TableAkey
INNER JOIN (select * from TableB 
            LEFT JOIN TableC ON TableB.tableBkey = TableC.tableBkey
            WHERE TableC.TableBkey is null )
AS b ON b.col1 = a.col1 AND b.col2 = a.col2 AND b.col3 = a.col3
WHERE c.TableBkey IS NULL
```